# touchBegan and TouchEnded overrides are affecting another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have this UIViewController in which i've overrided the touchBegan and touchEnded functions. I also have a button that segueues (push) to another view controller with an SKView on it. But the overrided function in the first controller are still active ei. the calculations done there are still showing on the second ViewController.

Maybe theres something im missing or something im assuming thats wrong. Any help would be appreciated

This is the first view controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class PortraitViewController: UIViewController {

    var vc: UIViewController?
    var startPoint: CGPoint?
    var endPoint: CGPoint?
    var movedPoint: CGPoint?
    var previousMove = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var beginTouch: UITouch?
    var scaleSum = 0
    var isPortrait = true
    let DEBUG: Bool = true


    // MARK:
    // MARK: Overriden Variables
    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{return .portrait}
    open override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{return .portrait}
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {return false}


    @IBAction func pinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if (isPortrait){
            let scale = sender.scale

            scaleSum += scale.exponent
            print(scaleSum)
            if(scaleSum > 10) {
                scaleSum = 0
                print(">10")
            }

            else if(scaleSum < -10) {
                print("<10")
            }
        }
    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if(isPortrait){
            if let theTouch = touches.first {
                endPoint = theTouch.location(in: self.view)

                let diffx = (endPoint!.x - startPoint!.x)
                let diffy = (endPoint!.y - startPoint!.y)

                if(diffx != 0 && diffy != 0){
                    let vector = CGVector(dx: diffx, dy: diffy)
                    var angle = atan2(vector.dy, vector.dx) * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI)
                    if angle < 0 { angle *= -1 } else { angle = 360 - angle }
                } 
            }
        }
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if(isPortrait){
            if let theTouch = touches.first {
                startPoint = theTouch.location(in: self.view)
            }
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
   //One of my attempts to jerry rig a solution
    @IBAction func prepToLandscape(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.isPortrait = false
        print("isPortrait = \(self.isPortrait)")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

This is the second view controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import SpriteKit

class LandScapeViewController: UIViewController {

    var vc: UIViewController?

    // MARK:
    // MARK: Overriden Variables
    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{return .landscape}
    open override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{return .landscapeLeft


    // MARK:
    // MARK: Functions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let controllerStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        vc = controllerStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Root")

    // Part of my attempt to jerry rig a solution
        let vcP: PortraitViewController = UIStoryboard(name:"Controller",bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PortraitController") as! PortraitViewController
        vcP.isPortrait = false
        print("vcP.isPortrait = \(vcP.isPortrait)")
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        let scene = GameScene(size: joystickView.bounds.size)
        scene.backgroundColor = .gray

        if let skView = joystickView as? SKView {
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            skView.backgroundColor = .red

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func toPortrait(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you trigger the segue to landscape? Is it done only in the storyboard?

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen Yea the segue was just a simple one done in the story board using show/push. I assumed there would be no issue.. Would that create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code shown is everything relevant, this makes sense. What's happening is this: the touch events are hit-tested to the `joystickView`, but because you haven't implemented a custom `touchesBegan(_:with:)` on that view, the touch event is passed up to the next `UIResponder` in the responder chain. That would be the `LandScapeViewController`. But that class also doesn't implement a custom `touchesBegan(_:with:)`, so the event passes to the next class, which in this case is `PortraitViewController`. Because `PortraitViewController` *does* implement that method, it gets called. There's your confusion.

To fix this, implement the `touches…` methods on `UIResponder` for either `joystickView` or `LandScapeViewController`, even if they do nothing – but don't call `super` in them! Note the following, from the [`touchesBegan(_:with:)` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan):

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, even if your implementations do nothing.

Where you're overriding `touchesBegan(_:with:)`, you probably don't want to call `super`. This is because the super implementation is the one that says "oh, shoot, I don't know how to handle this – pass it up the chain!" But when you handle the touch, it should end there, because *you're handling it!* So only call `super` when you're not handling the touch – which in your case looks like never, at least for `PortraitViewController`.

For more information, check out [Event Delivery: The Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html).

Comment: You're correct. Adding overrides that do nothing in the LandscapeViewController and removing the calls to super fixed the issue.  Your explanation was pretty clear. Thank you for the help and the link.